# How to ignore or skip empty string during scraping website?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, replace

When I do a website scraping, it lists these odds, but when it's empty (see picture), it makes a mistake. How do you please fix and implement it in the program?

When scraping, where I first list the names of players and then the odds, the names are listed fine, but then the odds are listed and at the moment where there is nothing at the place where the course is supposed to be, the program stops and writes an error. So I need to write to print an empty string when skipping an empty string, or to skip that line and move on, but I don't know how to implement it in the program.

For example:

```
if kurzy == "":
  print ("1")
```

or `continue` or `pass`...but doesn't work.

```
for match in matches:
    tymy = match.find('span', class_="c-events__teams").text
    if tymy == []:
        continue
    seznam.append(tymy)
    kurzy = match.find_all('span', class_="c-bets__inner") 
    
    x1.append([str(k.string) for k in kurzy[0]])
    x2.append([str(k.string) for k in kurzy[1]])
```

Example:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO. "it makes a mistake" is not a good problem description. Please describe the issue in more detail? If there is an exception, add the full error message to your post.

Comment: If I had to guess, either `kurzy == None` or `len(kurzy) < 2` causing `kurzy[0]` or `kurzy[1]` to cause an error. Add a check before the last 2 lines: `if kurzy and len(kurzy) >= 2):`

Comment: I fixed it to make you better understand

Comment: @neznamy Your additions are noticed and the rough direction is also clear, but more information is needed.  What is your expected outcome? Is there a url to refer to, ...?

Comment: when I add if kurzy and len(kurzy) >= 2:, the output is error: arrays must all be the same length :(

Comment: You need to determine what value `kurzy` has hwne there's no data so you can check for it. That seems like something you should be able to do…

Comment: Yes, its https://22bets.me/cs/line/Table-Tennis/ and i need Names, odd 1 and odd 2, that is all. But suddenly, when there is no number, it makes error.

Comment: I can't visit that site, when I try it says "Access to this site is disabled in the US". In my comment I meant "...what value kurzy has when there's no data''. Once you know that, you'll be able to put something in your code to handle it.